# Virtualbox host only + NAT network slow

Tags: centos, centos6, linux-networking, virtualbox

I have a Virtualbox CentOS 6.6 machine. It takes a very long amount of time to ssh (like 80 seconds), but once I log in it is not *as* slow. I also notice when pinging something like google.com from the console it takes 10-20 seconds to get going, but once the pings start happening I'm seeing 5 ms responses. When I removed the second interface (NAT) I was able to ssh to the machine immediately. What network configurations are necessary to allow NAT and Host only to work happily together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This very much looks like a DNS configuration problem inside the VM. Start from looking at */etc/resolv.conf* contents. My guess is that adding/removing interfaces may change routing table and this way influence name resolving. What happens when you change nameservers order? A result from `host -v google.com.` could help you find the correctly working nameserver from your current setup.

This can also be other timeout-related issue, but little can be said without further details, ie. relevant logs.

Comment: I second the DNS problem and to validate this with SSH, just add `UseDNS no` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and see if the connection will be made quicker.

Comment: Awesome. /etc/resolv.conf had google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 in it as well as our local company addresses below them. Removing google's fixed it. So. Is adding `PEERDNS=no` to the top of /etc/resolv.conf enough to keep dhclient's hands off of it in the future? Thanks.

Comment: Answering myself. No, that didn't stop it from overwriting. So the new addendum, is configuring dhclient the way to go then? It appears there is only a sample config and nothing other than that by default.

Comment: Ok...nvm....yes `PEERDNS=no` does stop dhclient from overwriting it. I put it in both `ifcfg-ethN` files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` for future interested people's reference. Thanks for the help.